# Show Front Camera Within Set Frame of View Controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice, facetime

I am trying to add the Front Camera as a subView to my existing View Controller.  I would like to set a frame for it, and be able to emulate the way a FaceTime call would look, with the Front Camera showing in the corner.  Here is what I have tried so far.

```
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [AVCaptureDeviceInput
                                    deviceInputWithDevice:[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]
                                    error:nil];;
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];
UIView *aView = self.view;
previewLayer.frame = aView.bounds; 
[aView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

But, this crashes with:

```
[AVCaptureDeviceInput setVideoPreviewLayer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Any thoughts? I don't need to actually record, just need to see the Front Camera on a smaller screen within the viewcontroller.

Comment: Why are you creating and assigning an AVCaptureDeviceInput to an AVCaptureSession variable? Are you sure that's your actual code, because that should throw all kinds or warnings and / or errors at compile time.

Comment: First attempt at using AVCaptureSession, and jumped on first example I could find.  All I want is to present a view, and a small subview in the corner.  That subview I want to be the Front Camera.  Could you point me in the correct direction?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the line `AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [AVCaptureDeviceInput …` is wrong. You can't assign an AVCaptureDeviceInput to a AVCaptureSession, because they're unrelated classes. Either you copied the wrong code, or this is seriously broken. It should throw compiler warnings at you, if not outright errors.

Comment: Definitely no errors or warnings whatsoever...until the app crashes.I got it from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html in the overview

Comment: No you did not. The line `AVCaptureSession *captureSession = <#Get a capture session#>;` means that you need to allocate an AVCaptureSession instance. An AVCaptureDeviceInput is not an AVCaptureSession subclass. They do not allocate and set an AVCaptureDeviceInput to an AVCaptureSession there. I suggest reading the appropriate section within their documentation for how to do this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2